# Minus 2 value in FastReport.net

Tags: fastreport

I want to Minus to value in FastReport.Net in footer.
my Code :

```
private void PageFooter1_BeforeLayout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Text22.Text=Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(Text12.Text)-Convert.ToDouble(Text3.Text));
    }
```

and this error was occurs:

```
FastReport.Net v1.7.33
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at FastReport.ReportScript.PageFooter1_BeforeLayout(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at FastReport.Code.ExpressionDescriptor.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at FastReport.BandBase.CalcHeight()
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.ShowBandToPreparedPages(BandBase band, Boolean getData)
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.ShowBand(BandBase band, Boolean getData)
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.EndLastPage()
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.RunReportPage(ReportPage page)
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.RunReportPages()
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.RunReportPages(ReportPage page)
   at FastReport.Engine.ReportEngine.Run(Boolean runDialogs, Boolean append, ReportPage page)
   at FastReport.Report.Prepare(Boolean append)
   at FastReport.Design.ReportTab.Preview()
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do `DataTextFormatString="{0:Axx}"`, and put the code into the `BeforePrint` event.

For example:

```
private void Text14_BeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text14.Text=string.Format("{0:N}",((Decimal)Report.GetColumnValue("Table.money"))-((Decimal)Report.GetColumnValue("Table.TRSMONEY")));
}
```